# How do I know when component's DOM is updated and finished transitions in Ractive?

Tags: custom-component, ractivejs

I'm trying to wrap [IScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5) library into Ractive component. Is there a way to be notified when component's DOM changed and finished any transitions so that I can update the scroller? I see the following ways to achieve this:

1. Declare dependencies (of the component's template) explicitly, like

   ```
   <Scroll context="{{...}}" > </Scroll>
   ```

   I can observe `context` variable, but still can't wait for  transitions to finish.
2. Patch Ractive.set() so that it emits custom event when used:

   ```
   // Broadcast promise returned by `set`.
   var oldset = Ractive.prototype.set;
   Ractive.prototype.set = function () {
     var ret = oldset.apply(this, arguments);
     this.fire('set', ret);
     return ret;
   };
   ```

   Then, in the component's initialization code, I can subscribe to the `set` event:

   ```
   this._parent.on('set', function (ret){
       ret.then(update);
   });
   ```

   This will not work for `Ractive.push()` and other methods. Also this will notify my component about all changes made by `set`-ting something, not only about those affecting component's DOM. Finally, I must explicitly refer to component's parent using `this._parent`, which means my components can not be nested.

So, is there are better way to achieve this in Ractive?

Answer (score 1):

The initialization options allow `oncomplete` (or ractive.on('complete'... if you prefer) for initial render. See http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/lifecycle-events

All of the data modification methods, [`set`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-set), `animate`, `push`, `slice`, etc. return a promise that will not be called until DOM is updated and transitions have completed.

Here's a simple example (http://jsfiddle.net/ctfyes7t/):

```
{{#if show}}
    <li intro='fade:{ duration: 2000 }'>ta da!</li>
{{/if}}

r.set('show', true).then(function(){
    // called when fade intro complete
});
```

Comment: I'm already using this behaviour (as well as `oncomplete` and intro transition). But how to do this from components code only and efficiently? I'd like to make a component self-contained (that is no additional code should be required to use it except for template). I believe it is a typical task to update some 3rd party widget wrapped into component when component's DOM updates.

Comment: All of those methods and techniques are available from within the component, so I'm not understanding where the gap is. If it's about exposing the "doneness" externally, you can fire event from within the component when it's ready.

Comment: Its my english, I suspect.  Changes happen on main Ractive app (say, data updates received over websocket). My component uses `{{yield}}` directive hence it implicitly depends on the parent's data. These updates may change component's DOM and trigger some transitions. I'd like to know when all transitions (within component) are finished, so that all styles and dimensions are settled and I may safely update the state of the 3rd party widget. Naturally I'd prefer to put all refresh logic into component, not to the main app.

Comment: I think I see now. The issue is that the `{{yield}}` belongs completely to the parent, so the component doesn't have any direct knowledge. Can you use `{{>content}}` instead? Then it would all run in the component. Otherwise you could raise an event in the parent and capture it in the component via `this.parent.on('eventName', function(){...})`.

Comment: I will think about `{{>content}}` again, but having to pass context explicitly looks less user-friendly at least. Moreover, even though in this case I could observe on that context, it would still be problematic to hook up to the end of transitions.  Thanks.

Comment: @SergeyBatalov One more thing that might be handy that I forgot about was `.container` and `.findContainer` which allow a component running in a `{{yield}}` to get a reference to the logical container. See [these tests](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/blob/dev/test/__tests/init/initialisation.js#L519-L544) for simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be approached from another direction: changes to the specific parts of DOM can be observed using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

So, I end up with the following approach to wrapping external widgets:
basically, we get component's top node (and initialize 3rd party code) using `intro` transition, and then in `oncomplete` callback register observer with something like this:

```
this.observer = new MutationObserver(update);
this.observer.observe(this.node, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    characterData: true,
    attributes: true, // transitions may change attributes
});
```

where function `update` updates 3rd-party widget.

[Here](https://github.com/svbatalov/ractive-component-iscroll) is the source code of the component.